# Enable direct transfer from iWork apps to my app

Tags: ios, iwork, uidocumentinteraction

I am investigating the possibilities of making an app that can handle iWork's apps documents (Pages, Numbers, Keynote). I have made the app and have registered the Document types, but this only gets me as far as supporting Open In from other apps that implements the UIDocumentInteractionController.

As far as I have been able to gather - The only possibility available currently is to implement a WebDAV service, and using it to sync the documents.

[Filesharing from pages](http://www.macobserver.com/tmo/article/file_sharing_with_an_ipad_ugh/)

Another possibility is to transfer using iTunes

[Sharing using iTunes](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1948/how-integrate-itunes-file-sharing-with-your-ios-app)

My conclusion: no direct transfer.

None of these options appeal to me, but the most reasonable is to implement a WebDAV service, like DropBox.

So, my question is - Does anyone have experience with enabling document transfers, in a direct manner - If so, how. If not, am I correct in saying that the WebDAV path is feasible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Direct app-to-app transfer will not work if the other app(s) do not cooperate with you. You would have to get Apple to offer an "Open In…" command in their iWork apps that uses `UIDocumentInteractionController` to make it work.

Comment: OK - I was afraid of that. I don't expect them to offer that option in time for me to use that feature. Thanks